# sql getting wrong outpout

Tags: sql

I'm doing an exercise and the first question is :

> 1- select the list of name with the mgr, in case the mgr is null show me 'President'

Now I'm quite new but how can I select all the column with a condition?

Comment: i dont think we learned the case so idk what to do

Comment: which db are you using..

Answer (score 0):

This would be done with a case expression, `IF()`, `IIF()`, `IFNULL()`, `ISNULL()`, `NVL()`, or a `COALESCE()` function depending on what you've learned so far and which RDBMS you are using in class.

- Nearly every RDBMS besides MS Access: `CASE WHEN mgr IS NULL THEN 'President' ELSE mgr END`
- Nearly every RDBMS besides MS Access: `COALESCE(mgr, 'President');`
- Mysql and MariaDB: `IFNULL(mgr, 'President')`
- MS SQL Server and MS Access: `ISNULL(mgr, 'President')`
- Oracle: `NVL(mgr, 'President')`
- Mysql and Mariadb: `IF(mgr IS NULL, 'President', mgr)`
- MS Access: `IIF(mgr is NULL, 'President', mgr)`

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any information about column names, so I am using made up column names.

This is the sample table. There are two columns in it.

```
EMP | MGR
----------
ABC | DEF
DEF | NULL
XYZ | HJK
HJK | NULL
OPQ | DEF
```

Based on your requirement, I believe that you are trying to write President instead of NULL.
So, this query might be working for you (This might need some changes based on your Database)

```
SELECT EMP,
       CASE
        WHEN MGR IS NOT NULL THEN MGR
        ELSE 'PRESIDENT'
       END AS 'MGR'
FROM MYTABLE;
```

Result should be like this:

```
EMP | MGR
----------
ABC | DEF
DEF | PRESIDENT
XYZ | HJK
HJK | PRESIDENT
OPQ | DEF
```